# Examples for Kawamata-Viehweg vanishing fails without normal crossing condition

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Kawamata-Viehweg's vanishing theorem states that on a nonsingular projective variety $X$, for a nef and big $\mathbb{Q}$-divisor $D$ whose non-integral part $D-[D]$ is normal crossing on $X$, we have $H^i(X,O_X([-D]))=0$ for $i \leq n-1$.

(In Kawamata's proof, normal crossing is assumed to apply a covering lemma, which claims for any assigned positive multiple of irreducible components of a normal crossing divisor $D$ on $X$, we have a finite flat morphism $X'\to X$ where the inverse image of the $D$ has assigned multiplicity and the support is normal crossing.)

Is there an example showing that the normal crossing condition cannot be dropped?